# Why do I see the PHP code and not the output of the script?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, installation

I have installed Apache. Its working fine.

I have also PHP 5.2.1 installed.

I have enabled load module in http.conf also

I have also added following in mime.types

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source  phps
```

But Still I am .php page along with php code. It gets executed but also shows the php code same as written. What else configuration remaining?

Solutions:
Add SetHandler in http.conf file

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you seem to have fixed it (as posted in other comments), I think I see your problem.

The `AddType` directive seems to like having a dot in the extension.  Your posted configuration is missing them.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: Should we add the given code in mime.types or http.conf

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [php](http://www.php.net/downloads.php)?

Or you can try other popular packages for basic web server functionality:

- [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/xampp.html)
- [Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/products/server/)

Comment: or WAMP or EasyPHP

Comment: Yeah I do Have installed PHP. Its in c:\php folder. I am trying to do it manually... not using xampp or zend server

Comment: check this: http://www.php.net/manual/de/install.windows.apache2.php and follow 'Installing as an Apache handler'

Comment: thnx.. addhandler worked.... Actually i found out that i placed my add type code placed in next file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to restart Apache after making the config changes?

Also clear your browser's cache - this was the problem the last time I had this issue. I went so far as using another browser to make sure.

Comment: yeah fine its working now... I use addhandler method